# If sendmail is on primary domain, should i setup spf records?

Tags: sendmail, spam, spf

I have a web server and sendmail on same domain, where letters are sent to users with confirmation code. Sometimes these letters are marked as spam and sometimes even are don't delivered.

Can the problem exist because of spf records missing for main domain? 
I understand that question can be stupid.. but i have no idea why letters can be marked as spam :(

P.S. For a moment i have assigned google mail servers and spf records (to have team emailboxes on gmail) to my domain dns records, but i believe that this should not affect normal messages delivery from my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email delivery can be tricky sometimes, especially with everything people do to block spam.

I would read your mail server logs to see if you get any messages why.  Sometimes, you can detect a server configuration error that way (e.g., not HELO'ing properly).  SPF could be a part of it too.  I would configure that properly.

Also, I would look at mail that was received and marked as spam.  Sometimes, spam filters will put information about why a message was marked as spam in the email headers.  Usually it will be an [X-SOMETHING] header.  See, for example: http://www.ipswitch.com/support/imail/guide/2006/imail_server_wh/X_Header_Explanations.htm

Also, I would look at DNS blacklists.  Just check if your server is listed in a blacklist.  You can look here: http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx